# how to prevent scripts being injected on my website

Tags: logging, injection

I have an API server on Digitalocean. Yesterday they told me I have "a large flood of traffic from one or more of your servers that is disrupting the normal traffic flow for other users."

I checked my running processes and it appears that someone injected a script and run it with `root` permission. The pic is as follows:

[image]

the thing is I can't even find this file `udp_flood.txt`. and I don't even know how one can get by `root` permission so easily..

My guess is in my backend I have an API that let user upload their images to the site. And then I crop / resize the image and upload to AWS. But I couldn't be sure this is the cause of the problem so I don't know how to prevent future injections too.

So my questions are:

1. how he did it to inject scripts and run as root?
2. how to prevent it? is it safe to say the cause is coming from upload functionality?
3. how to log it so in the future I know I am being attacked? (instead of my service provider telling me)

Comment: There is about a million things you could have done wrong. Pinpointing the vulnerablility would require a forensic analysis which we can't provide remotely on a Q&A site. I voted to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad". However: here's a few tidbits: That `whereis` command is wrong. Try `find / | grep udp_flood.txt`. But from the googling the filename I'm guessing this file: http://pastebin.com/fjpRH1wm (Which is [known to VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b2f64da8eb8f00ffff3772586a04b7f7e1a0bfa5cf33d08e007906b7c7c15113/analysis/).)

Comment: sure. thanks but @SteffenUllrich also pointed out a few good points.  thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how he did it to inject scripts and run as root?

This is not known based on the few details you have provided. It might through brute-forcing SSH logins. It might also through combining several problems. A simple upload is not enough because the attacker must also find ways to execute the code and must also have found a security issue which allows to gain root access for a normal user (there are various exploits for this on unpatched Linux systems).

> how to prevent it? ...how to log it so in the future I know I am being attacked? (instead of my service provider telling me)

Use a fully patched system, find and fix security problems in your application, use strong passwords for remote login (or better keys) ... There are [lots of similar questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=secure+server) about this topic already.

Based on the current knowledge you have I you look instead for a managed system to keep the system secure and look for expertise in web application security to make the application secure. There is way to much to look out for and cannot be shown in detail just in a single answer (too broad).

> is it safe to say the cause is coming from upload functionality?

Not without doing a proper forensic analysis of the system.

See also [I was hacked, but I don't know why](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73453/i-was-hacked-but-i-dont-know-why/73455#73455).

Comment: I see. My guess is not brute-forcing SSH otherwise he could have done much more than that.. Also the os is ubuntu 14.04..

Comment: @Shih-MinLee: root access make it possible to do everything and it does not matter how it was gained. Apart from that whereis is only usable to find real commands, not simple text files which are used as the input to some other program (i.e. perl in this case).

Comment: first I am trying to check ssh logins using `last` command. I see many different ips but I login from home and it has static ips so I still cannot quite tell if there's people who actually ssh in this instance.. or is there something else I can do?

Comment: You can put up honeypots, even for SSH. Some IDS may also log the attempts.

Comment: @Shih-MinLee: again - asking about what can be done is too broad, because there are simply too much things to watch for. If you have more specific questions please ask a new question and don't add a comment with the question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your info. just that I don't even know the cause of the problem so all I can do is changing password and configure sshd for now.. and this is also why I ask point 3 how do I log things so that when attack happens again in the future I know who did it, how he did it.. etc

Comment: @Shih-MinLee: There are a lot of attack vectors and probably several of them are specific to your web application or your server setup. Essentially you ask us to help you protect a system with unknown setup running unknown software where some unknown attacker mounted some unknown attack. This is not only too broad but impossible.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich gotcha. I talked to another guy who faced exactly the same attack yesterday.  Surprisingly he's using digitalocean service.  Any chance we can deduct more about how to got attacked using this information?

Comment: @Shih-MinLee: the only thing you can probably deduct is that there are lots of guys out there who attack servers. You should also know that brute forcing SSH connections and looking for known bugs in installed web applications is an automated process today.

Comment: Same here. Digital Ocean droplet - flood script running from /tmp folder.

Comment: Here it's Clojure web app running behind an nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Same flooded ip address.

Comment: Found some binary garbage in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: In my case it could have been this attack: http://antirez.com/news/96
We are running redis here.